# Add item to array in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm having trouble adding items to array in Vue.

**I'm not getting errors on console and it won't add the items to the array.**

I need two methods so each time I click on an item select button it gets added or removed from the array **selectedGifts**.

**Buttons**

```
<span class="select-gift button" v-on:click="addGift(gift)">Elegir</span>
<span class="select-gift button" v-on:click="removeGift(gift)">Elegir</span>
```

**Methods**

```
addGift(gift) {
  this.selectedGifts.push(gift)
},
removeGift(gift) {
  this.selectedGifts.splice(gift)
},
```

**Data**

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  delimiters: ["<%","%>"],
  data() {
    return {
      recipient: '',
      message: '',
      selectedBox: null,
      selectedCard: null,
      selectedGift: null,
      selectedGifts: [],
```

Any help please?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: What exactly is happening and how are you passing ``gift``? is there a ``v-for``?

Comment: What kind of "trouble" are you referring to? You need to add more details in your question.

Comment: I'm not getting errors on console and it won't add the items to the array, what am I missing?